# Getting form values in angular 4 from a semantic modal

Tags: angular, typescript, modal-dialog, semantic-ui

I have implemented a semantic-ui modal in my angular app. My modal consist of a simple form and I am trying to pass the data of the form to a function in my typescript file. 
My modal code:

```
<div class="ui modal" id="newRoom">
   <div class="ui icon header">
     <i class="add square icon"></i>
      Add new Room
   </div>
   <div class="content">
   <form class="ui form"
      #form=ngForm
      (ngSubmit)="addChatRoom(form)">
    <div class="field">
     <label>Name</label>
     <input type="text" name="roomName" placeholder="Enter the room name">
    </div>
    <div class="field">
     <label>Description</label>
     <input type="text" name="roomDescription" placeholder="Enter the 
        description">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <button class="ui red  cancel inverted button">
      <i class="remove icon"></i>
      Cancel
    </button>
    <button class="ui green ok inverted button" type="submit" >
      <i class="checkmark icon" ></i>
      Add
    </button>
   </div>
   </form>
  </div>
 </div>
```

My typescript code:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {HomeService} from './home.service';
import {NgForm} from "@angular/forms";

@Component({
   selector: 'app-home',
   templateUrl: './home.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  chatRooms: any;
  constructor(public homeService: HomeService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  addChatRoom(form: NgForm) {
     const chatRoomName = form.value.roomName;
     const description  = form.value.roomDescription;
  }
}
```

both the variables "chatRoomName" and "description" are undefined.
Please help

Comment: Can you create a JSfiddle so we can run the sample

Comment: ok. will do that

Comment: @MichaelTempest actually i have never done this and while trying it i am having some problem. Is there any alternative to that ?